# Is there anything that can only be achieved by ApplicationContext but ActivityContext or vice versa?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Is there anything that can only be achieved by `ApplicationContext` but `ActivityContext` or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

`getApplicationContext()` is almost always wrong. Ms. Hackborn (among others) have been very explicit that you only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know why you are using `getApplicationContext()` and only when you need to use `getApplicationContext()`.

To be blunt, "some programmers" use `getApplicationContext()` (or `getBaseContext()`, to a lesser extent) because their Java experience is limited. They implement an inner class (e.g., an `OnClickListener` for a Button in an Activity) and need a Context. Rather than using `MyActivity.this` to get at the outer class' this, they use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()` to get a Context object.

You only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know you need a Context for something that may live longer than any other likely Context you have at your disposal. Scenarios include:

Use `getApplicationContext()` if you need something tied to a Context that itself will have global scope. I use `getApplicationContext()`, for example, in `WakefulIntentService`, for the static `WakeLock` to be used for the service. Since that `WakeLock` is static, and I need a `Context` to get at `PowerManager` to create it, it is safest to use `getApplicationContext()`.

Use `getApplicationContext()` when you bind to a `Service` from an `Activity`, if you wish to pass the `ServiceConnection` (i.e., the handle to the binding) between `Activity` instances via `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`. Android internally tracks bindings via these `ServiceConnections` and holds references to the `Context`s that create the bindings. If you bind from the `Activity`, then the new `Activity` instance will have a reference to the `ServiceConnection` which has an implicit reference to the old `Activity`, and the old `Activity` cannot be garbage collected.